# how to force compiler to use the correct overloaded method in c++ for a templated class

Tags: c++, methods

I want to create a next element method for a Fibonacci class im working on for a c++ class im taking but I want it to work for strings and longs without  having to write two separate methods.

I wrote a templated function but the compiler couldn't check the if statement so it would always say can use `std::to_string()` on a string type and the compiler would fail.

So I had to make two methods to deal with string and longs

```
        template <typename T>
        void fib<T>::next_ele(){
            if(typeid(a_) == typeid(long(0))){
                std::cout<<typeid(a_).name();
                T nextp = a_ + b_;
                seq_+=",";
                seq_+=std::to_string(nextp);
                a_ = b_;
                b_ = nextp;     
            }
            else{
                T nexte = b_ + a_;
                seq_+=",";
                seq_+=nexte;
                a_ = b_;
                b_ = nexte;
            }

        }
```

main program

```
        #include "fibclass.h"
        #include <typeinfo>
        #include <string>
        using std::string;
        #include <iostream>
        using std::cout; using std::endl;

        int main(){

            cus::fib<long> a;
            cout<<a<<endl;
            for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
                a.next_ele(4);
            }

            cout<<a<<endl;
            cus::fib<string> b("a","b");
            for(int i = 1; i<=6; i++){
                b.next_ele("p");
        }
            cout<<b;
        }
```

header with the two different methods basically a work around

```
        #ifndef FIBH
        #define FIBH

        #include <string>
        using std::string;
        #include <typeinfo>
        #include <iostream>
        namespace cus{
            template <typename T>
            class fib{
                private:

                public:
                    string seq_;
                    T a_;
                    T b_;
                    fib() : seq_("0,1") , a_(long(0)), b_(long(1)){};
                    fib(T a, T b) : seq_(""), a_(a), b_(b) {};
                    void next_ele(long);
                    void next_ele(string);
                    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,fib& f){
                out<<f.seq_;
                return out;
            };


            };

        template <typename T>
        void fib<T>::next_ele(long b){
            long nextp = a_ + b_;
            seq_+=",";
            seq_+=std::to_string(nextp);
            a_ = b_;
            b_ = nextp; 
        }   
        template <typename T>
        void fib<T>::next_ele(string a){
                string nexte = b_ + a_;
                if (!(seq_.empty()))
                    seq_+=",";
                seq_+=nexte;
                a_ = b_;
                b_ = nexte;
            }

        }

        #endif
```

Comment: Google for "template specialization".  You'll wind up writing separate methods anyway.

Comment: Okay so how would I format the methods to recognize whether to call the long method or the string method thanks for your help

Comment: I think I have a solution for you, but do you understand that the statement `T nexte = b_ + a_;` will just concatenate the strings together and not actually "add" anything?  The result will be an ever increasing string of zeros and ones. (e.g. `1010110101101101`) and not anything that represents a Fibonacci sequnce. If that's what you want, I'll share my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: the problem it's the `std::to_string()` function. That exist for `long` but don't exit for `std::string`.

And `std::to_string()` its compiled even when `T` is `std::string` (also if that part of code isn't executed).

If you **really** want a single method (but... what's wrong with specialization?)... I suppose you can use `std::ostringstream`, that works with integers and strings, instead of `std::to_string()`; something like

```
template <typename T>
   void fib<T>::next_ele(){

      std::cout << "typename is [" << typeid(a_).name() << "]\n";

      std::ostringstream  oss;

      T nextpe = ( typeid(a_) == typeid(long(0)) ? a_ + b_ : b_ + a_ );

      oss << ',' << nextpe;

      seq_ += oss.str();
      a_    = b_;
      b_    = nextpe;
   }
```

p.s.1: If you use `std::ostringstream`, remember to include `<sstream>`.

p.s.2: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thank you! this is the answer I was looking for